# Not saving data in typeorm mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, websocket, socket.io, nestjs, typeorm

I have a webSocket message resource in nestjs.

My problem is that I send the data to the server with postman, and the data reaches the service correctly, but it is not saved in the database.

I use Typeorm and mongodb database.

I have two other resources in the project and they work correctly (they are REST).

messages.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagesService } from './messages.service';
import { MessagesGateway } from './messages.gateway';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MessageEntity } from './entities/message.entity';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { RoomsModule } from '../rooms/rooms.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MessageEntity]),
    UsersModule,
    RoomsModule,
  ],
  providers: [MessagesGateway, MessagesService],
})
export class MessagesModule {}
```

messages.gateway.ts:

```
import {
  WebSocketGateway,
  SubscribeMessage,
  MessageBody,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { MessagesService } from './messages.service';
import { CreateMessageDto } from './dto/create-message.dto';
import { UpdateMessageDto } from './dto/update-message.dto';
import { ObjectId } from 'typeorm';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(8081)
export class MessagesGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  constructor(private readonly messagesService: MessagesService) {}

  @SubscribeMessage('createMessage')
  async create(@MessageBody() createMessageDto: CreateMessageDto) {
    console.log(
      'Received createMessage event with createMeesageDto:',
      createMessageDto,
    );
    const message = await this.messagesService.create(createMessageDto);

    if (message) {
      this.server.emit('createMessage', message);
    } else {
      this.server.emit('createMessage', 'Something is wrong');
    }
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('findAllMessages')
  findAll() {
    this.server.emit('findAllMessages', this.messagesService.findAll());
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('findOneMessage')
  findOne(@MessageBody() id: ObjectId) {
    return this.messagesService.findOne(id);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('updateMessage')
  update(@MessageBody() updateMessageDto: UpdateMessageDto) {
    return this.messagesService.update(updateMessageDto.id, updateMessageDto);
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('removeMessage')
  remove(@MessageBody() id: number) {
    return this.messagesService.remove(id);
  }
}
```

messages.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MessageEntity } from './entities/message.entity';
import { CreateMessageDto } from './dto/create-message.dto';
import { UpdateMessageDto } from './dto/update-message.dto';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import { RoomsService } from '../rooms/rooms.service';

@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {
  constructor(
    private roomsService: RoomsService,
    private usersService: UsersService,
    @InjectRepository(MessageEntity)
    private messageRepo: Repository<MessageEntity>,
  ) {}

  async create(createMessageDto: CreateMessageDto) {
    try {
      const { content, senderUsername, roomLink } = createMessageDto;

      const sender = await this.usersService.findOne(senderUsername);

      const room = await this.roomsService.findOne(roomLink);

      if (!sender) throw new Error('Sender not found');
      if (!room) throw new Error('Room not found');

      const message = this.messageRepo.create({
        content,
        sender,
        room,
      });

      const savedMessage = await this.messageRepo.save(message);
      return savedMessage;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error('something wrong!');
    }
  }

  async findAll() {
    return await this.messageRepo.find();
  }

  async findOne(id: ObjectId) {
    return await this.messageRepo.findOne({ where: { id } });
  }

  async update(id: number, updateMessageDto: UpdateMessageDto) {
    await this.messageRepo.update(id, updateMessageDto);

    return { updated: true };
  }

  async remove(id: number) {
    await this.messageRepo.delete(id);

    return { deleted: true };
  }
}
```

create-message.dto.ts:

```
import { IsMongoId, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateMessageDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  content: string;

  @IsMongoId()
  senderUsername: string;

  @IsMongoId()
  roomLink: string;
}
```

The data that I send in postman on the createMessage event:

```
{
  "content": "Hello world!",
  "senderUsername": "john_doe",
  "roomLink": "world"
}
```

I expect a new message to be created in the messaegs collection, but it's not.